# Load content in div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a jQuery code to load contents from link in a modal window. this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loading = $('<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading">');

    $('#page-help').each(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .append($loading.clone());
        var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr('href'))
                .dialog({
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<a id="page-help" href="index2.html">Test</a>
```

i want to load contents in a **DIV**, not in a **modal window**!
How i can do this? :(

Comment: is the div for the modal already existing on page load? You can use the $.load method in jquery: $('#id_of_your_div').load('page.php');

Comment: could u please give me a full code? i dont know what should i do with your code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method in jquery:

First you must have a div where you want to load the content to:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<img id="img" src="loading.gif" style="display:none;"/>
```

Then in your script:

```
$('#page-help').click(function(){
    $('#img').show();
    $('#container').load('index2.html', function(){
       $('#img').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: one more thing, how i can add loading image?
<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading">

Comment: I've edited the answer, basically you're going to need to hide an image on page load and then show it up once the user clicks on the link, and then hide it again once the content has loaded. You can do this by using a callback function.

Answer (score 2):

I found a best answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6949666/1158603 if you want to load some external page's content into div

```
<a href="/page1">Load Page 1</a>
<a href="/page2">Load Page 2</a>
<a href="/page3">Load Page 3</a>
<a href="/page4">Load Page 4</a>

<div id="LoadMe">Where external page will load into</div>
```

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('#LoadMe').load($(this).attr('href'));

  return false;
});
```